# HtmlUnit does not execute code library ocrad.js

Tags: java, javascript, html, ocr, htmlunit

I would like that HtmlUnit the execution of the file aaa.html also made the Javascript code with OCR library.

Code Java:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    HtmlPage testPage = null;
    URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("aaa.html");
    try{
        testPage = webClient.getPage(url);
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Code html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="ocrad.js"></script>
        <script>
            function readText(image) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
                canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;

                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                var parsedText = OCRAD(canvas);

                var output = document.getElementById("text");
                output.innerHTML = parsedText;
            };
        </script>

        <div class="entranceFade first">
            <img onload="readText(this)" id="image" src="file.png"/>
        </div>

        <div class="entranceFade second">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <canvas id="canvas" class="border">
                This browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag
            </canvas>
        </div>

        <div class="entranceFade third">
            <div id="text"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Dependency Maven to HtmlUnit:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Html file and ocrad.js I have a Maven project resourse.

And the printed result:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: missing name after . operator (file:/C:/Users/lll/Test/target/classes/ocrad.js#1)
```

This library comes from:

```
https://github.com/antimatter15/ocrad.js/blob/master/ocrad.js
```

Do you have any solution to HtmlUnit started to process the library code?